# Since Android studio 2.1 update DDMS won't open

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms, android-device-monitor

I've update my android studio to 2.1 and also downloaded the new Android N Preview.

Since this I can't open Android Device Monitor(DDMS).

It seems it has been deleted from my PC or it can't be located because it's moved or something?

I don't even get any error messages! When I click on Android Device Monitor it just does nothing.

I am using a 64bit Windows 7 machine with JDK 8u72

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: i have also updated but i have not updated  to N version and it is opening perfectly from top bar symbol of ddms

Comment: I have the N preview since a while, and I have also updated to AS 2.1. DDMS is throwing up an error on opening, but then it's working ok. I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got DDMS back by doing the following things:

1. By removing Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools and the Android N preview
2. Installing Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools

I haven't yet tried to reïnstall the Android N preview, so I don't know if that will give the problem again.

Comment: I tried this on my Mac, using Android Studio 2.1.1, but it didn't work.